# Check String for identical Digits

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm asking my users to enter a 4 - 6 digit numberic PIN. And I'd like to make sure users can't enter 0000 or 11111 or 333333. How can I check a string for 4 consecutive identical digits? I'm using vb.net.

Comment: This is a RegEx job.  Google "regex match repeating digits".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code snippet below:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a As String = "001111"
    Dim b As String = "1123134"
    Dim c As String = "1111"

    Console.WriteLine(CheckConsecutiveChars(a, 4)) 'True => Invalid Pin
    Console.WriteLine(CheckConsecutiveChars(b, 4)) 'False => Valid Pin
    Console.WriteLine(CheckConsecutiveChars(c, 4)) 'True => Invalid Pin
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub


'maxnumber = maximum number of identical consecutive characters in a string
Public Function CheckConsecutiveChars(ByVal j As String, ByVal maxNumber As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim index As Integer = 0
    While ((index + maxNumber) <= j.Length)
        If (j.Substring(index, maxNumber).Distinct.Count = 1) Then
            Return True
        End If
        index = index + 1
    End While
    Return False

End Function
```

The method `String.Distinct.Count()` counts the number of distinct characters in a string. You cast your digit to a String and test for the number of different characters. If the result is 1 then the user has entered the same number.

**Note:** If you're using the `Substring`, you must check the length of the string first (is it long enough) to avoid exceptions.

Comment: So does that just check for distinct characters, or consecutive indentical chractors? i.e. 121311 has 4 1's in, but could be a valid PIN, as they are not consecutive. using the `String.Distinct.Count()` it would return 4, and fail?

Comment: It would indeed return 4. there are 4 unique chars present. But as the string is 6 long, there is no possibility for them to contain 4 consecutive identical digits. to be 100% sure you'de need to iterate the string and for each char check the following 4 chars.

Comment: Please check the first codesnippet. I believe that's what your looking for.

Comment: While this works, it create many unnecessary temporary strings using the `Substring` method.  You can just examine each character and keep track of how many consecutive duplicates there are.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Major point made there. Although i don't expect to much of a problem seen the limited length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to the accepted answer, but does not create lots of temporary strings in memory.

```
'maxnumber = maximum number of identical consecutive characters in a string
Public Function HasConsecutiveChars(ByVal j As String, ByVal maxNumber As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Dim consecutiveChars As Integer = 1
    Dim prevChar As Char = "x"c

    For Each c in j
        If c = prevChar Then
            consecutiveChars += 1
            If consecutiveChars >= maxNumber Then
                result = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            consecutiveChars = 1
        End If

        prevChar = c
    Next

    Return result

End Function
```